# RedHat Openshift - Monitoring - Processes inside containter

Tags: docker, process, openshift, monitoring, cadvisor

Is a dedicated solution to monitoring all processes inside each one container starting in openshift environment ?

Yes, i know cAdvisor can do this, but i have a problem with configuration this solution in openshift and looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure elk(elasticsearch,Logstash,kibana) +  email alert (etsy/411 or elastalert) for this. Add filebeat client in each container which will send all apps logs to ELK.

Add healcheck with liveness check in each container for you app, which will restart the container if that check not come true. you can add these in metrics too.